# How to display message in console during test when element is not found with robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

i want to know how to display a message in console when an element is not found with robot framework:

I tried this:

```
S2L.Wait Until Page Contains Element  ${checkbox}  10s checkbox  not found
```

It's not working for this element and don't know why. It works for any other element but not for my checkbox.

So for now i have this:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  5 times  2 sec  S2L.Click Element ${checkbox}
```

But when it fails it says only the element not found bu i would prefer to code a personalized message.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you

Comment: Please show the actual code with proper formatting so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: my problem is to format correctly the code. it was easy before i clicked on the code icon but now it's difficult.

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: Is that your actual code? Do you only have one space between `10s` and `checkbox`? Also, you wrote _"It's not working for this element and don't know why. "_ - what does "not working" mean? What happens when that statement runs?

Comment: "not working" means in my case when i run the test, if the checkbox is not displayed robot framework just ignores the element. It happens only with this element. The space between 10s and checkbox is 4.

Comment: So, you're saying you go to the page, you claim the page doesn't have the element but selenium claims it does? While selenium isn't foolproof, your assessment seems unlikely. A bug that big would have been caught. What makes you so sure that the checkbutton element isn't there? What have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do think that your problem is something different, your question can be answered. `Run Keyword And Return Status` will capture the error and continue and provide a status. `Run Keyword If` then allows for using the keyword `Fail` and it will also generate a message on the console.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers 

*** Test Cases ***
Wait And Click succesfully
    Open Browser    http://google.com    HeadlessChrome
    Wait and Click Element    name:q    This should work

Wait And Click unsuccesfully
    Open Browser    http://google.com    HeadlessChrome
    Wait and Click Element    name:nobtn      This should not work

*** Keywords ***
Wait and Click Element
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${message}=None

    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status
    ...                Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  
    ...                    5 times  2 sec  
    ...                    Click Element   ${locator}

    Run Keyword If    
    ...    "${status}" == "False"
    ...    Fail     ${message}
```

Comment: Thank you Kootstra, i will try.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the error argument available with the Wait Until Page Contains Element keyword?

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=elementId    timeout=60s    error=Display whatever you want, e.g. Lorem Ipsum...
```